# line integral of $\frac{x dx + ydy }{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} } $ along any path inside the annulus joining two concentric circles (viewed as shells)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, line-integrals

> Find $\int \frac{x dx + ydy }{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} } $
>   along any path inside the shell joining the concentric shells $x^2 + y^2 = R_1^2 $ and
>   $x^2 + y^2 = R_2^2$, where $R_1 < R_2$

To find the line integral, I choose my path as 
$$\alpha(r,\theta) = (r, \theta_0),$$
for some $\theta_0\in [0, 2\pi]$.

so for $$f(r,\theta) = (cos\theta, sin\theta)$$

we have

$$ d\alpha(r,\theta) = (dr, 0)
\\ \int f d\alpha = \int_{R_1}^{R_2} cos\theta_0 dr = cos(\theta_0) (R_2 - R_1),$$
which means the line integral does depend on the angle that we choose, but the answer provided to us claims that the answer is $$R_2 - R_1$$, so my question is that is there anything wrong in my calculations ?

Comment: Is the denominator of your vector field **really** $\;\sqrt{x+2+y^2}\;$ , or should it be $\;\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\;$ ...?

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for pointing out, see my edit please.

Comment: I also assume you meant any *closed, simple smooth path" in that annulus, right? But then it'd be easier to take **any** circle between those two radii...

Comment: One last thing: is the numerator what you wrote, or is it **really** $\;y\,\color{red}{dy}+y\,\color{red}{dx}\;$ ? Or maybe it is $\;x\,dx\color{red}-y\,dy\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio We are taking line integral and connecting two surfaces of shells which are concentric. In your answer, you are computing completely a different thing.

Comment: Hint: $xdx+ydy=d(x^2+y^2)/2=d(r^2/2)=rdr$, so $(xdx+ydy)/\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=dr$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas First, I've no idea why you call shells to what all the world call simply "circles" (or even "canonical circles", as their center is the plane's origin). Second,  the space between two concentric circles is called "annulus", yet you call it, again!, "shell". Third, your question **clearly says** "any path **inside the shell**, which I translate as "any path inside the annulus". Since you give not more information, how in the world are we going to infer you meant "segment of line joining both circels' perimeters"?!

Comment: @J.G. Please put your enlightening hint as a (short) answer !

Comment: @DuchampGerard Done.

Comment: thks, this helps, indeed (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you chose the path to be with a constant angle, meaning
$$\theta(t)=\theta_0 , r(t)=R_1+(R_2-R_1)t$$
$$\vec{r}(t) = r(t)\cdot (\cos \theta_0 , \sin \theta_0) $$
$$ \vec{dr} = \frac{dr}{dt} dt (\cos \theta_0 , \sin \theta_0)  = (R_2-R_1)(\cos \theta_0 , \sin \theta_0)$$
and so,
$$\vec{f}\cdot \vec{dr} = (R_2-R_1)dt $$
And the integral will be 
$$\int_0^1 (R_2-R_1) dt = R_2-R_1$$
The answer doesn't depend on $\theta_0$!

---

Moreover, you can calculate the potential $\phi$ creating $\vec{f}$ and by the gradient theorem,
$$\phi(b)-\phi(a) = \int \nabla \phi \cdot \vec{dr} = \int \vec{f}\cdot \vec{dr}$$

In polar coordinates,
$$\vec{f} = \hat{r}$$
and so 
$$\phi(r,\theta)=r$$ meaning each circle is an equai-potential - again confirming the answer doesn't depend on the angle.

Answer (score 2):

Since $xdx+ydy=d(r^2)/2=rdr$, your integral is $\int_{R_1}^{R_2}dr$, which is the desired answer.